# Laravel 5 : Getting error while creating laravel project in ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I have created a laravel project in windows 7,it's working fine.But when i create it in ubuntu through command prompt using command : composer create-project laravel/laravel lara,getting error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.3, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

like this

But it's creating the project folder inside opt/lampp/htdocs and while i'm running this getting error in browser like this:

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/l5/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/l5/public/index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/l5/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/l5/public/index.php on line 24
```

Please help me to get this ,i'm a beginner in laravel and ubuntu.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install mbstring using the below command

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring
```

Then try `composer install` again

Comment: i have run this command and after that create laravel project but getting an error in browser

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lara1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

Comment: Give 0777 permission to your laravel project folder and try again

Comment: Check phpinfo(); in server make sure it is 7.0

Comment: this is because “??”only can be used in php 7 or more higher.

Comment: Try these commands sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.0

Comment: Did you check in browser for phpinfo() not in cli

Comment: Sorry... PHP Version 5.6.30 in browser for phpinfo().but in command prompt it's displaying 7.0.22

Comment: Try using a2dismod php5.6 and a2enmod php7.0

Comment: ERROR: Module php5.6 does not exist! while running command a2dismod php5.6

Comment: L O V E L Y  dear jani